# Is Multiple '/boot' partition required for different Linux OS?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I assume that that a single `/swap` & `/home` partition will suffice for different os but each root `/` partition to be created for each of them but not sure whether each `/boot` partition are required or a single `/boot` partition will take care of the all linux os?

Comment: Hello anjan, welcome on SU. Take a look to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/844990/257269)...

Comment: I would have a separate partition for each installation, each with its own `/` and subdirectories, where you can mount `/home` in each case to a single, shared partition, though I can still see problems: if you have personal binaries, these may not link to compatible libraries on the different installations; applications save configurations to `.` files in `~`, and these may differ between installations; and there could be problems with user/group IDs. So I would retain the `/home` directories, but link `~/Documents`, etc, to directories in a shared partition mounted in (say) `/home/common`.

Answer (score 0):

One boot loader (e.g. GNU Grub) can handle multiple operating systems. Different operating systems may handle installation differently though. If you install windows after linux generally windows will overwrite your linux boot loader so it is best to install windows first then any flavors of linux you would like.

About the actual boot partition, [this question might be relevant](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6490/is-a-boot-partition-necessary-anymore)